# How to Get Form Input as Float64 in Go

Tags: string, math, go, int

I have a webform built using Go.  Users enter a number, then I need to do some math on that number.  It seems like all methods using http package use strings as the output.

How can I do simple math on the user input?

Here is the basic code I have:

```
func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", root)
    http.HandleFunc("/result", result)
}

// handle the root url
func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, inputForm)
}

// root url html
const inputForm = `<html>
<body>
  <form action="/result" method="post">
    <div>Number between 0 and 1
       <input type="text" name="anar">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
`

func result(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    input := r.FormValue("anar")  // FormValue is always string

    // add number to input
    newNum := input + 0.25

    // stuff to output result
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the input to a float first using [`strconv.ParseFloat`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat)

```
fval, err := strconv.ParseFloat(input, 64)

if err != nil { 
    log.Println(err)
    //do something about it
}

newNum = fval + 0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

A friend just gave me this answer using fmt package.  I thought I would share it too.

```
type userInput struct {
    Num float64
}

input := "0.50"
s, err := fmt.Sscanf(input, "%f", &userInput.Num)
newNum := userInput.Num + 0.25
```

Comment: While this works just fine, it would be much slower than using strconv, since Sscanf has to parse the input, parse the format string and use reflection to assign the value.